# avoid text separation between text and list environment

Tags: formatting, environments, lists, text

I have some text and a subsequent list, but a table defined elsewhere is placed by latex in between.

My code is something like:

```
It is found that:
\begin{compactitem}
    \item blabla
    \item blabla2
\end{compactitem}
```

but even is the table is placed somewhere else and marked with [h!] it appears between "It is found that:" and the subsequent list.

Is there a way to avoid this placement in between, i.e. make the text "bind" to the list environment?

I know you can do this in text, e.g. using the special character ~, but I do not know how to join the text and a given environment.

Thank you very much for your time.

Best
Aleix

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide an example of document which show your problem. Float can move on bage, but with placement option `[!ht]˛and if it is not inserted between text and list.

Comment: Following your "code is something like" I believe that the answer is "something like". Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass... to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem and what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your suggestions, but producing a MWE would take me long since my situation was the consequence of several coincidences regarding the positioning of text and a table. I recalled that minipages created indivisible  content. It worked, as follows:

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
It is found that:
\begin{compactitem}
    \item blabla
    \item blabla2
\end{compactitem}
\end{minipage}
```

Best
Aleix

Comment: But this can cause new problem: empty space at bottom of page if there is not enough space for `minipage` and it is pushed to top of next page. I rather manually  move inserting of `table` or `figure` floats that your problem will not happen ...

Comment: True, that may happen as well. However, in my case there is a lot of text afterwards, so if this is the only caveat, it will not affect me. BTW, how do you manually move the insertion of the table? I usually use the option [h!] in the table environment but it usually gets moved anyway...

Comment: OIption `[!h]` is bad choice and cause problems (move all floats to the end of document). Far better and correct is use of `[!ht]˛` or `[htbp]` which gives to  LaTeX more choice for moving floats to the appropriate position in document. With these placement options you will less troubles than with your solution.